# Vim: Writing function skeleton

Tags: formatting, vim

When writing new functions with Vim I always seem to have to do a bit of "manual" work.

x = Cursor position

If I start typing a function and insert a couple of curly braces and the end

```
function Apples() {x}
```

Then hit **Enter**, it obviously looks like this

```
function Apples() {
x}
```

Which results in me having to **ESC,O** in order to shift the closing curlybrace down.
While this may seem like a trivial matter, doing this over the last 5 months is getting bothersome, and I know there are plenty like me out there who knows there should be an elegant solution to this. I am open to plugin-suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple mapping like this one (there are dozens of variants floating around SO and the web):

```
inoremap {} {<CR>}<C-o>O
```

You can also search [www.vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php) for a dedicated plugin.

But I strongly recommend you to try a snippet-expansion plugin like [Snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) or [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips). Both plugins follow the same model but they have slightly different snippet syntaxes and features. It works like that:

1. you type a trigger:

   ```
   fun
   ```
2. you hit `<Tab>` and you get the following with `function_name` in select mode:

   ```
   function [function_name]() {

   }
   ```
3. you type your desired name:

   ```
   function Apples|() {

   }
   ```
4. you hit `<Tab>` to place the cursor between the parentheses:

   ```
   function Apples(|) {

   }
   ```
5. you hit `<Tab>` again to place the cursor on the line below with the correct indentation:

   ```
   function Apples() {
       |
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

With [lh-bracket](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets) (in C or C++ mode), when you hit `enter` whilst in between two brackets, the newlines you are expecting are inserted.

The idea is to test for: `getline(".")[col(".")-2:col(".")-1]=="{}"` and execute/insert `"\<cr>\<esc>O"` when the condition is true, or `"\<cr>"` otherwise.

Within lh-bracket, I have the following [into a C-ftplugin](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/map-tools/trunk/after/ftplugin/c/c_brackets.vim#162):

```
call lh#brackets#enrich_imap('<cr>',
          \ {'condition': 'getline(".")[col(".")-2:col(".")-1]=="{}"',
          \   'action': 'Cpp_Add2NewLinesBetweenBrackets()'},
          \ 1,
          \ '\<cr\>'
          \ )
function! Cpp_Add2NewLinesBetweenBrackets()
  return "\<cr>\<esc>O"
endfunction
```

I guess (code not tested) it would (*) translate into:

```
" put it into ftplugin/{yourfiltetype, javascript?}.vim
inoremap <buffer> <silent> <expr> <cr> s:SmartCR()

function s:SmartCR()
    return getline(".")[col(".")-2:col(".")-1]=="{}"
    \ ? "\<cr>\<esc>O"
    \ : "\<cr>"
endfunction
```

(*) Actually, `lh#brackets#enrich_imap` does a few other things (the mapping is compatible with LaTeXSuite's IMAP.vim presence ; the mapping can be toggled on/off along with all the other mappings from lh-brackets)